# How to swap the position of two buttons with constraint layout?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm am trying to swap the position of two buttons around when something in app happens, however I do not believe that it is working because the layout is causing the buttons to stay as they are set to be a certain amount of "dp" away from each other so that I can have them where I want on the screen. Is there a way to fix this, such as: Swapping the layout properties of each button or using different layout methods to have the buttons where I want on the screen.
The code I am using to swap the buttons around is:

```
float posX = answer1.getX();
float posY = answer1.getY();
float pos2X = answer2.getX();
float pos2Y = answer2.getY();
answer2.setX(posX);
answer2.setY(posY);
answer1.setX(pos2X);
answer1.setY(pos2Y);
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess that might be helpful. Have you considered swapping the buttons themselves instead of touching their positions?

```
Button temp1 = answer1;
Button temp2 = answer2;

answer1 = temp2;
answer2 = temp1;
```